# Ionic: How to center a div?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

**THE SITUATION:**

I am making an app using [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/docs/). In one page i need to display an image. This image has to be horizontally centered.

**ATTEMPT 1:**

Following the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-offset) i have divided one row into three equal columns and put the image in the second one.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-33"></div>
    <div class="col col-33">
        <img src="{{ data.logo }}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33"></div>
 </div>
```

But unfortunately the image is far to be centered. Tend to stay in the left half of the screen.

**ATTEMPT 2:**

Trying with some old css tricks.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <img src=" {{ data.logo }} " alt="" >
</div>
```

But again i am not getting the desired result.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i center a div in Ionic framework?

Comment: `<center></center>` worked for me. Don't no way it's been deprecated in html standard

Comment: `<center>` is obsolete and not supported in HTML5. It's been strongly recommended not to use styling tags in structural documents such as HTML for a long time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In [Ionic Framework 2](http://ionicframework.com/) you could now use the [attribute directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) `center` and `text-center` for that.

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col text-center>
    <a href="#">My centered text</a>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 55):

You already found your answer but I would do something like that instead:

**In your css:**

```
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

And then just add this class to your image:

```
 <img src="{{ data.logo }}" class="center" alt="">
```

This way you don't need to adjust each image on its own and I find this very descriptive when you look at the HTML. Also, it is not restricted to a specific image size.

Answer (score 6):

Your 2nd attempt works if you add the `width` style. The width should be the width of the image.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100px">
    <img src=" {{ data.logo }} " alt="" >
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, will require some extra work to get the width of each image but seems working properly. Strange is not contemplated in Ionic grid system no?

Answer (score 4):

This should work, just add `col-center`class:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col col-33"></div>
   <div class="col col-33 col-center">
      <img src="{{ data.logo }}" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="col col-33"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "col-center" is for vertical centring.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```html
<div align="center">
    <img style="height:100px;width:100px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/JavaScript-logo.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To allign a div center, margin 0 auto is still the best option but for this you need to provide a proper space to the div to find the center section of it and therefore you need to provide it some with.

Along with `margin 0 auto` also give a proper width so your div can find a center location of it.